# NullPointerException al instanciar

Tags: java

Estoy construyendo un prototipo de agenda para guardar datos y citas. Debo estar cometiendo algún error tonto que no logro ver. Al crear una instancia me da error. Os dejo parte del código a ver si podéis ver que ocasiona el NullPointerException.

```
public class Agenda {

String nombreAgenda;

List<Cita> listaCitas;
Set<DayOfWeek> diasNoHabiles;
Map<String, IntervaloFechas> mapaPeriodos;
final int MAX_CITAS_DIA;

public Agenda(String nombreAgenda, int MAX_CITAS_DIA, Set<DayOfWeek> diasNoHabiles,
        Map<String, IntervaloFechas> mapaPeriodos) {

}

public static Agenda buildSampleAgenda() {
    Cliente[] clientes;
    Cita c1;

    Agenda sample = new Agenda("SAMPLE", 10, noHabiles, noLaborables);

    clientes = Persona.buildSamplePersonas();

    c1 = new Cita(clientes[0], LocalDateTime.parse("2019-02-19T20:00:00"), "Arreglar frigorífico.");

    sample.listaCitas.add(c1);

    return sample;

}

}
```

He omitido parte del código, pero en conclusión es que tengo un método constructor y otro estático que me construye la Agenda. 
Recalco que todo me funciona correctamente y se crea la instancia, hasta que intento agregar un elemento a la lista:

```
sample.listaCitas.add(c1);
```

Si hago:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Agenda nueva = Agenda.buildSampleAgenda();

}
```

me marca NullPointerException en la línea de añadir a la lista...

A ver como podría subsanar el error.

Gracias, un saludo a la comunidad.

Comment: Sí sé que es una pregunta recurrente. He leído ese post, he probado a inicializar, entre otros consejos, pero... aún no he visto el fallo. Gracias.

Comment: Falta código para poder ver cual sería el problema, aun así es algo que tienes que depurar. Seguramente `listaCitas` sea `null` o `sample` y al acceder a el es cuando salta el `NPE`.

Comment: Añade código faltante y muestranos el log.

Comment: como sabes que se creo bien la instancia? listaCitas esta siendo inicializado?

Comment: Ya está solucionado. Error muy tonto por mi parte. No estaba inicializado del todo. Me faltaba ésto: List<Cita> listaCitas = new ArrayList<Cita>(); osea la segunda parte. Gracias a todos por aclararme un poco.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cuando accedes a listaCitas para añadir el elemento c1 aún no has inicializado esta variable y debido a eso te salta el NullPointerException.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución. recuerda revisar [ask] para conocer como realizar respuestas en el sitio, saludos.